# Creating a comma separated list from IList<string> or IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, string

What is the cleanest way to create a comma-separated list of string values from an `IList<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`?

`String.Join(...)` operates on a `string[]` so can be cumbersome to work with when types such as `IList<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` cannot easily be converted into a string array.

Comment: Oh... whoops. I missed the addition of the ToArray extension method in 3.5: `public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`

Comment: If you've come to this question looking for a means of writing CSV, it's worth remembering that simply inserting commas between items is insufficient and will cause failure in the case of quotes and commas in the source data.

Answer (score 1787, accepted):

**.NET 4+**

```
IList<string> strings = new List<string>{"1","2","testing"};
string joined = string.Join(",", strings);
```

**Detail & Pre .Net 4.0 Solutions**

`IEnumerable<string>` can be converted into a string array *very* easily with LINQ (.NET 3.5):

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;
string[] array = strings.ToArray();
```

It's easy enough to write the equivalent helper method if you need to:

```
public static T[] ToArray(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return new List<T>(source).ToArray();
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = ...;
string[] array = Helpers.ToArray(strings);
```

You can then call `string.Join`. Of course, you don't *have* to use a helper method:

```
// C# 3 and .NET 3.5 way:
string joined = string.Join(",", strings.ToArray());
// C# 2 and .NET 2.0 way:
string joined = string.Join(",", new List<string>(strings).ToArray());
```

The latter is a bit of a mouthful though :)

This is likely to be the simplest way to do it, and quite performant as well - there are other questions about exactly what the performance is like, including (but not limited to) [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219519/whats-the-c-method-syntax-for-converting-an-array-to-a-simple-string).

As of .NET 4.0, there are more overloads available in [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join), so you can actually just write:

```
string joined = string.Join(",", strings);
```

Much simpler :)

Comment: The helper method involves creating two unnecessary lists.  Is this really the best way to solve the problem?  Why not concatenate it yourself in a foreach loop?

Comment: The helper method only creates *one* list and *one* array. The point is that the result needs to be an array, not a list... and you need to know the size of an array before you start. Best practice says you shouldn't enumerate a source more than once in LINQ unless you have to - it might be doing all kinds of nasty stuff. So, you're left with reading into buffers and resizing as you go - which is exactly what `List<T>` does. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: No, the point is that the result needs to be a concatenated string.  There's no need to create a new list or a new array to achieve this goal.  This kind of .NET mentality makes me sad.

Comment: That's it.  Every answer leads to Jon Skeet.  I am just going to var PurchaseBooks = AmazonContainer.Where(p => p.Author == "Jon Skeet").Select();

Comment: Thanks! This helped me too. @JonSkeet Is it wrong to have gone this far with one line (collecting int IDs)? string myStr = string.Join(",", (from a in foo select a.someInt.ToString()).ToList());

Comment: @codeMonkey0110: Well there's no point in having a query expression there, or calling `ToList`. It's fine to use `string myStr = string.Join(",", foo.Select(a => a.someInt.ToString()))` though.

Answer (score 188):

FYI, the .NET 4.0 version of `string.Join()` has some [extra overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx), that work with `IEnumerable` instead of just arrays, including one that can deal with any type `T`:

```
public static string Join(string separator, IEnumerable<string> values)
public static string Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)
```

Comment: This will call the T.ToString() method ?

Comment: Was just about to comment this on Jon's answer. Thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Anyway to do this on a property of an object? (Ex:  IEnumerable<Employee> and the Employee object has a string .SSN property on it, and getting a comma separated list of SSN's.)

Comment: You have to select the string first, though you could create an extension method that does that. `str = emps.Select(e => e.SSN).Join(",")`

Answer (score 74):

The easiest way I can see to do this is using the LINQ `Aggregate` method:

```
string commaSeparatedList = input.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x)
```

Comment: That's not only more complicated (IMO) than ToArray + Join, it's also somewhat inefficient - with a large input sequence, that's going to start performing very badly.

Comment: Still, it's the prettiest.

Comment: You can feed Aggregate a StringBuilder seed, then your Aggregate Func becomes `Func<StringBuilder,string,StringBuider>`. Then just call `ToString()` on the returned StringBuilder. It's of course not as pretty though :)

Comment: This is the clearest way of doing what the question asked for IMHO.

Comment: Beware that `input.Count` should be more than 1.

Comment: @Youngjae is right! Beware.  To guard against the null/count issue try this: `string commaSeparatedList = input == null || !input.Any() ? "" : input.Aggregate((a, x) => a + ", " + x);`  Note that it does work with Count == 1

Comment: The time complexity of this "solution" is quadratic. I would mark it as a bug if I saw code like this.

Answer (score 36):

I think that the cleanest way to create a comma-separated list of string values is simply:

```
string.Join<string>(",", stringEnumerable);
```

Here is a full example:

```
IEnumerable<string> stringEnumerable= new List<string>();
stringList.Add("Comma");
stringList.Add("Separated");

string.Join<string>(",", stringEnumerable);
```

There is no need to make a helper function, this is built into .NET 4.0 and above.

Comment: Note that this is applicable starting with .NET 4 (as Xavier pointed out in his answer).

Comment: From the standpoint of .NET 4 newbie with less than a month's experience this answer was a nice combination of correctness and succinctness

Answer (score 24):

If the strings you want to join are in List of Objects, then you can do something like this too:

```
var studentNames = string.Join(", ", students.Select(x => x.name));
```

Comment: Can we somehow skip adding the empty/null values to the studentNames? Because currently, x.name takes all values even if the x.name has null values

Comment: @Lucifer you can try this:
var studentNames = string.Join(", ", students.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).Select(x => x.name));

Answer (score 19):

Comparing by performance the winner is "Loop it, sb.Append it, and do back step".
Actually "enumerable and manual move next" is the same good (consider stddev).

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.5, OS=Windows 10.0.14393
Processor=Intel Core i5-2500K CPU 3.30GHz (Sandy Bridge), ProcessorCount=4
Frequency=3233539 Hz, Resolution=309.2587 ns, Timer=TSC
  [Host] : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.6.1637.0
  Clr    : Clr 4.0.30319.42000, 64bit RyuJIT-v4.6.1637.0
  Core   : .NET Core 4.6.25009.03, 64bit RyuJIT


                Method |  Job | Runtime |     Mean |     Error |    StdDev |      Min |      Max |   Median | Rank |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
---------------------- |----- |-------- |---------:|----------:|----------:|---------:|---------:|---------:|-----:|-------:|----------:|
            StringJoin |  Clr |     Clr | 28.24 us | 0.4381 us | 0.3659 us | 27.68 us | 29.10 us | 28.21 us |    8 | 4.9969 |   16.3 kB |
 SeparatorSubstitution |  Clr |     Clr | 17.90 us | 0.2900 us | 0.2712 us | 17.55 us | 18.37 us | 17.80 us |    6 | 4.9296 |  16.27 kB |
     SeparatorStepBack |  Clr |     Clr | 16.81 us | 0.1289 us | 0.1206 us | 16.64 us | 17.05 us | 16.81 us |    2 | 4.9459 |  16.27 kB |
            Enumerable |  Clr |     Clr | 17.27 us | 0.0736 us | 0.0615 us | 17.17 us | 17.36 us | 17.29 us |    4 | 4.9377 |  16.27 kB |
            StringJoin | Core |    Core | 27.51 us | 0.5340 us | 0.4995 us | 26.80 us | 28.25 us | 27.51 us |    7 | 5.0296 |  16.26 kB |
 SeparatorSubstitution | Core |    Core | 17.37 us | 0.1664 us | 0.1557 us | 17.15 us | 17.68 us | 17.39 us |    5 | 4.9622 |  16.22 kB |
     SeparatorStepBack | Core |    Core | 15.65 us | 0.1545 us | 0.1290 us | 15.45 us | 15.82 us | 15.66 us |    1 | 4.9622 |  16.22 kB |
            Enumerable | Core |    Core | 17.00 us | 0.0905 us | 0.0654 us | 16.93 us | 17.12 us | 16.98 us |    3 | 4.9622 |  16.22 kB |
```

Code:

```
public class BenchmarkStringUnion
{
    List<string> testData = new List<string>();
    public BenchmarkStringUnion()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
            testData.Add(i.ToString());
        }
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public string StringJoin()
    {
        var text = string.Join<string>(",", testData);
        return text;
    }
    [Benchmark]
    public string SeparatorSubstitution()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var separator = String.Empty;
        foreach (var value in testData)
        {
            sb.Append(separator).Append(value);
            separator = ",";
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string SeparatorStepBack()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in testData)
            sb.Append(item).Append(',');
        if (sb.Length>=1) 
            sb.Length--;
        return sb.ToString();
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public string Enumerable()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var e = testData.GetEnumerator();
        bool  moveNext = e.MoveNext();
        while (moveNext)
        {
            sb.Append(e.Current);
            moveNext = e.MoveNext();
            if (moveNext) 
                sb.Append(",");
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet was used

Answer (score 14):

Since I reached here while searching to join on a specific property of a list of objects (and not the ToString() of it) here's an addition to the accepted answer:

```
var commaDelimited = string.Join(",", students.Where(i => i.Category == studentCategory)
                                 .Select(i => i.FirstName));
```

Comment: Every single time I need to do this, I think "I really should take a few minutes to figure out how to do this in one line using string.Join(...)" but then I end up just foreach-ing it and moving on. Thanks for posting this!  :)

Answer (score 9):

Here's another extension method:

```
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> source, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, source);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Arriving a little late to this discussion but this is my contribution fwiw. I have an `IList<Guid> OrderIds` to be converted to a CSV string but following is generic and works unmodified with other types:

```
string csv = OrderIds.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
             (sb, v) => sb.Append(v).Append(","),
             sb => {if (0 < sb.Length) sb.Length--; return sb.ToString();});
```

Short and sweet, uses StringBuilder for constructing new string, shrinks StringBuilder length by one to remove last comma and returns CSV string.

I've updated this to use multiple `Append()`'s to add string + comma. From James' feedback I used Reflector to have a look at `StringBuilder.AppendFormat()`. Turns out `AppendFormat()` uses a StringBuilder to construct the format string which makes it less efficient in this context than just using multiple `Appends()`'s.

Comment: Gazumped, thanks Xavier I wasn't aware of that update in .Net4. The project I'm working on hasn't made the leap yet so I'll keep using my now pedestrian example in the meantime.

Comment: This will fail with a zero-item IEnumerable source. sb.Length-- needs a bounds check.

Comment: Nice catch thanks James, in the context where I'm using this I'm "guaranteed" to have at least one OrderId. I've updated both the example and my own code to include the bounds check (just to be sure).

Comment: @James I think calling sb.Length-- a hack is a little harsh. Effectively I'm just avoiding your "if (notdone)" test until the end rather than doing it in each iteration.

Comment: @david.clarke No I don't think it's too harsh; a `StringBuilder` is meant to be used most optimally by just doing `Append()` operations until your string is complete. I'm not sure why you seem to imply you are gaining anything here by avoiding the `if (notdone)` test until the end. The `notdone` variable stores the last result of `MoveNext()` which is called anyway on the `IEnumerable` interface in both of these solutions.

Comment: @James my point is there is often more than one correct answer to questions asked here and referring to one as a "hack" implies it is incorrect which I would dispute. For the small number of guids I'm concatenating Daniel's answer above would probably be perfectly adequate and it's certainly more succinct/readable then my answer. I am using this in only one place in my code and I will only ever use a comma as a delimiter. YAGNI says don't build something you aren't going to need. DRY is applicable if I needed to do it more than once at which point I would create an exension method. HTH.

Answer (score 8):

Specific need when we should surround by ', by ex:

```
        string[] arr = { "jj", "laa", "123" };
        List<string> myList = arr.ToList();

        // 'jj', 'laa', '123'
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ",
            myList.ConvertAll(m =>
                string.Format("'{0}'", m)).ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 7):

Something a bit fugly, but it works:

```
string divisionsCSV = String.Join(",", ((List<IDivisionView>)divisions).ConvertAll<string>(d => d.DivisionID.ToString("b")).ToArray());
```

Gives you a CSV from a List after you give it the convertor (in this case d => d.DivisionID.ToString("b")).

Hacky but works - could be made into an extension method perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

Here's the way I did it, using the way I have done it in other languages:

```
private string ToStringList<T>(IEnumerable<T> list, string delimiter)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  string separator = String.Empty;
  foreach (T value in list)
  {
    sb.Append(separator).Append(value);
    separator = delimiter;
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

We have a utility function, something like this:

```
public static string Join<T>( string delimiter, 
    IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, string> convert )
{
    return string.Join( delimiter, 
        collection.Select( convert ).ToArray() );
}
```

Which can be used for joining lots of collections easily:

```
int[] ids = {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233};

string csv = StringUtility.Join(",", ids, i => i.ToString() );
```

Note that we have the collection param before the lambda because intellisense then picks up the collection type.

If you already have an enumeration of strings all you need to do is the ToArray:

```
string csv = string.Join( ",", myStrings.ToArray() );
```

Comment: I have an extension method that does almost exactly the same thing, very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/696850/opportunities-to-use-func-to-improve-code-readability/709875#709875

Comment: Yeah, you could write this as a .ToDelimitedString extension method easily enough. I'd go with my single line string.Join one rather than using a StringBuilder an trimming the last char.

Answer (score 3):

you can convert the IList to an array using ToArray and then run a string.join command on the array.

```
Dim strs As New List(Of String)
Dim arr As Array
arr = strs.ToArray
```

Answer (score 3):

They can be easily converted to an array using the Linq extensions in .NET 3.5.

```
   var stringArray = stringList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use something like the following after you have it converted to an array using one of the of methods listed by others:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Configuration;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommaDelimitedStringCollection commaStr = new CommaDelimitedStringCollection();
            string[] itemList = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
            commaStr.AddRange(itemList);
            Console.WriteLine(commaStr.ToString()); //Outputs Test1,Test2,Test3
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** [Here](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2007/08/25/c---How-to-create-a-comma-seperated-string-from.aspx) is another example

Answer (score 3):

My answer is like above Aggregate solution but should be less call-stack heavy since there are no explicit delegate calls:

```
public static string ToCommaDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        sb.Append(item.ToString());
        sb.Append(',');
    }
    if (sb.Length >= 1) sb.Length--;
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Of course, one can extend the signature to be delimiter-independent. I'm really not a fan of the sb.Remove() call and I'd like to refactor it to be a straight-up while-loop over an IEnumerable and use MoveNext() to determine whether or not to write a comma. I'll fiddle around and post that solution if I come upon it.

---

Here's what I wanted initially:

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter, Func<T, string> converter)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var en = source.GetEnumerator();
    bool notdone = en.MoveNext();
    while (notdone)
    {
        sb.Append(converter(en.Current));
        notdone = en.MoveNext();
        if (notdone) sb.Append(delimiter);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

No temporary array or list storage required and no `StringBuilder` `Remove()` or `Length--` hack required.

In my framework library I made a few variations on this method signature, every combination of including the `delimiter` and the `converter` parameters with usage of `","` and `x.ToString()` as defaults, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully this is the simplest way

```
 string Commaseplist;
 string[] itemList = { "Test1", "Test2", "Test3" };
 Commaseplist = string.join(",",itemList);
 Console.WriteLine(Commaseplist); //Outputs Test1,Test2,Test3
```

Answer (score 3):

I just solved this issue before happening across this article. My solution goes something like below :

```
   private static string GetSeparator<T>(IList<T> list, T item)
   {
       return (list.IndexOf(item) == list.Count - 1) ? "" : ", ";
   }
```

Called like:

```
List<thing> myThings;
string tidyString;

foreach (var thing in myThings)
{
     tidyString += string.format("Thing {0} is a {1}", thing.id, thing.name) + GetSeparator(myThings, thing);
}
```

I could also have just as easily expressed as such and would have also been more efficient:

```
string.Join(“,”, myThings.Select(t => string.format(“Thing {0} is a {1}”, t.id, t.name));
```

Answer (score 3):

I came over this discussion while searching for a good C# method to join strings like it is done with the MySql method `CONCAT_WS()`. This method differs from the `string.Join()` method in that it does not add the separator sign if strings are NULL or empty.

> CONCAT_WS(', ',tbl.Lastname,tbl.Firstname)

will return only `Lastname` if firstname is empty, whilst

> string.Join(", ", strLastname, strFirstname)

will return `strLastname + ", "` in the same case.

Wanting the first behavior, I wrote the following methods:

```
    public static string JoinStringsIfNotNullOrEmpty(string strSeparator, string strA, string strB, string strC = "")
    {
        return JoinStringsIfNotNullOrEmpty(strSeparator, new[] {strA, strB, strC});
    }

    public static string JoinStringsIfNotNullOrEmpty(string strSeparator, string[] arrayStrings)
    {
        if (strSeparator == null)
            strSeparator = "";
        if (arrayStrings == null)
            return "";
        string strRetVal = arrayStrings.Where(str => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(str)).Aggregate("", (current, str) => current + (str + strSeparator));
        int trimEndStartIndex = strRetVal.Length - strSeparator.Length;
        if (trimEndStartIndex>0)
            strRetVal = strRetVal.Remove(trimEndStartIndex);
        return strRetVal;
    }
```

Comment: Alternative:
`string separator = ", ";
string strA = "High";
string strB = "";
string strC = "Five";
string strD = null;

var myStrings = new List<string> { strA, strB, strC, strD };
IEnumerable<string> myValidStrings = myStrings.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item));
return string.Join(separator, myValidStrings );`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.ToArray()` on `Lists` and `IEnumerables`, and then use `String.Join()` as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a few extension methods to do it in a way that's efficient:

```
    public static string JoinWithDelimiter(this IEnumerable<String> that, string delim) {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var s in that) {
            sb.AppendToList(s,delim);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This depends on

```
    public static string AppendToList(this String s, string item, string delim) {
        if (s.Length == 0) {
            return item;
        }

        return s+delim+item;
    }
```

Comment: Using the + operator to concatenate strings is not great because it will cause a new string to be allocated each time. Further more, although the StringBuilder can be implicitly cast to a string, doing so frequently (every iteration of your loop) would largely defeat the purpose of having a string builder.

Answer (score 1):

To create a comma separated list from an `IList<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>`, besides using `string.Join()` you can use the `StringBuilder.AppendJoin` method:

```
new StringBuilder().AppendJoin(", ", itemList).ToString();
```

or

```
$"{new StringBuilder().AppendJoin(", ", itemList)}";
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's bit late to answer this question but it might be helpful who land up here searching answer for this issue.

You could do something like below:

```
var finalString = String.Join(",", ExampleArrayOfObjects.Where(newList => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(newList.TestParameter)).Select(newList => newList.TestParameter));
```

Using ExampleArrayOfObjects.Where we will create new objectlist with non-empty values

And then further using .Select over that new objectlist to join with "," as a separator and make final string.