# How can I set a ComboBox text to a comma-delimited list of selected items?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, combobox

I have WPF ComboBox containing CheckBox items, and it allows the user to select multiple items.

I want to display the list of selected items as comma seperated text on the combobox after the user has selected an item from the combobox.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox  Name="cmbEnvironment"  >
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
var lstEnvironment = new List<Environment>();
lstEnvironment.Add( new Environment() { Name = "Env1", IsSelected = false});
lstEnvironment.Add(new Environment() { Name = "Env2", IsSelected = false });
lstEnvironment.Add(new Environment() { Name = "Env3", IsSelected = false });
cmbEnvironment.ItemsSource = lstEnvironment;
```

Model:

```
public class Environment
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Due to the behavior you want, wouldn't a better solution be that expands on click (`Expander`, `Popup`, etc)  with something like an `ItemsControl` or `ListView` used to display your items? Otherwise you might get some strange selection or open/close behavior.

Comment: What is the actual question? (I'm sure you don't just want to know that yes, somebody has probably implemented a similar combobox).

Comment: The question is how to show selected items comma seperated string as combobox text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the behavior you want, wouldn't a better solution be that expands on click (`Expander`, `Popup`, etc)  with something like an `ItemsControl` or `ListView` used to display your items? Otherwise you might get some strange selection or open/close behavior.

But anyways, personally I would create a data class containing:

```
string SelectedItems { get; set; }
ObservableCollection<Enviornment> AvailableItems { get; set; }
```

And do something like this:

and add PropertyChange notifications to your `Enviornment` class so you can do something like this:

```
foreach(var item in AvailableItems)
    item.PropertyChanged += Environment_PropertyChanged;

...

void Environment_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected")
        SelectedItems = string.Join(",", 
            availableItems.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
            .Select(p => p.Name).ToArray());
}
```

(I can't remember if `ToArray()` is part of the framework or not, however if not then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799454/302677) has a good extension method to easily converting a List to an Array so you can use it in `string.Join`)

However using your current setup you could also just add some code-behind to the `CheckBox.CheckChanged` or `ComboBox.SelectionChanged` to cast `cmbEnvironment.ItemsSource` to `List<Environment>`, build a comma-delimited string of the Checked items, then set `cmbEnvironment.Text` equal to your comma-delimited string.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have used expander control with a listview to achive the same.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers: I recommend the (free) [Extended WPF toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox) for this, it includes a CheckComboBox that does exactly this.