# Elegant way of creating a comma separated list, and removing trailing comma

Tags: c#

When I generate comma separated lists, I hate how I have to chop off the trailing comma.

Is there a better way?  I do this fairly often so looking for opinions.

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.Count; x++)
{
  sb.Append(list[x].Name);
  sb.Append(",");
}

var result = sb.toString().Substring(0, result.length - 2);
```

Comment: `String.join(",", string[])`?

Comment: Not c# but generically stated - if not first item, prepend a ','

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring

Answer (score 25):

Use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) and Linq's [IEnumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) extension method.

```
var str = String.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.Name));
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Description

You can use the `String.Join` and the `Enumerable.Select` (namespace System.Linq) method

> **String.Join** Concatenates all the elements of a string array, using the specified separator between each element.
>
> **Enumerable.Select** Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

#### Sample

```
String.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.Name));
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)
- [MSDN - Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

Comment: This will add a trailing comma if the list contains an item with null name

Answer (score 5):

Base case:

```
string.Join(",",list.Select(l => l.Name));
```

with null checks:

```
string.Join(",",list.Where(l => l != null).Select(l => l.Name));
```

with null/empty checks:

```
string.Join(",",list.Where(l => l != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Name)).Select(l => l.Name));
```

with trimming:

```
string.Join(",",list.Select(l => l.Name.Trim()));
```

with both:

```
string.Join(",",list.Where(l => l != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(l.Name)).Select(l => l.Name.Trim()));
```

Comment: Starting with .net 4.0, There is string.Join(String, IEnumerable<String>) and hence no need for ToArray()

Comment: can this also trim the string so there arent' any blank spaces?  i should do a null check on the list before hand right?

Comment: @user1361315 most complete method of doing that would be  `list.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.Name).Select(n => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(n))` -- though arguably less elegant.

Comment: Yes you can do `String.Join(",", list.Select(x => x.Name.Trim()));` and to check for nulls: `String.Join(",", list.Select(x => (x.Name != null) ? x.Name.Trim() : null));` (You can have null values in the sequence of strings you pass to `String.Join()`)

Answer (score 1):

If performance is an issue, I wouldn't suggest this, but it is possible to use the `Aggregate` method of LINQ to do such a concatenation.

e.g.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication14
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Example> list = new List<Example>()
            {
                new Example() { Name = "John Doe" },
                new Example() { Name = "Jane Doe" },
                new Example() { Name = "Fred Doe" },
            };

            string s = list.Select(item => item.Name)
                           .Aggregate((accumulator, iterator) => accumulator += "," + iterator);
        }
    }

    public class Example
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This could be useful, however, if your joining logic ends up being more complicated (a rare occurrence, I would suspect).

Answer (score 0):

And one inelegant solution without `Join`

```
for(int x = 0; x < list.Count; x++)
{
    if (x > 0)
        sb.Append(",");

    sb.Append(list[x].Name);
}


var result = sb.toString();
```