# In Razor, how do I print a loop with delimiter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code:

```
            @foreach (UserAccount ua in company.Users) {
                @ua.userName, 
            }
```

Which would print:

```
user1, user2, user3,
```

How do I get rid of the last ","?

Comment: replace it with for and add the last username separately

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx):

```
@(string.Join(company.Users.Select(u => u.UserName), ", "))
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work because it doesn't know which field to print:  userName.  So it just print the object toString().

Answer (score 5):

use [String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx) method. it will handle the last comma for you.

```
@(string.Join(company.Users.Select(x => x.userName), ", "))
```