# Convert a list of strings to a single string

Tags: c#, string, list

```
List<string> MyList = (List<string>)Session["MyList"];
```

`MyList` contains values like: `12` `34` `55` `23`.

I tried using the code below, however the values disappear.

```
string Something = Convert.ToString(MyList);
```

I also need each value to be separated with a comma ("`,`").

How can I convert `List<string> Mylist` to `string`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a comma separated list from IList<string> or IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring)

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
string Something = string.Join(",", MyList);
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this code:

```
var list = new List<string> {"12", "13", "14"};
var result = string.Join(",", list);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The result is: `"12,13,14"`

Answer (score 8):

Or, if you're concerned about performance, you could use a loop,

```
var myList = new List<string> { "11", "22", "33" };
var myString = "";
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (string s in myList)
{
    sb.Append(s).Append(",");
}

myString = sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1).ToString(); // Removes last ","
```

[This Benchmark](https://gist.github.com/ArcticWinter/6963107) shows that using the above loop is ~16% faster than `String.Join()` (averaged over 3 runs).

Answer (score 8):

Entirely alternatively you can use LINQ, and do as following:

```
string finalString = collection.Aggregate("", (current, s) => current + (s + ","));
```

However, for pure readability, I suggest using either the loop version, or the string.Join mechanism.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the syntax? Am I correct in assuming the first argument to be the return string, which will be concatenated with the second argument? What are the variables `current `and `s` exactly, current string and current value?

Answer (score 6):

You can make an extension method for this, so it will be also more readable:

```
public static class GenericListExtensions
{
    public static string ToString<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        return string.Join(",", list);
    }
}
```

And then you can:

```
string Something = MyList.ToString<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to add an extra bit over the accepted answer. Without it, Unity threw this error:

```
cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' expression to type `string[]'
```

The solution was to use `.ToArray()`

```
List<int> stringNums = new List<string>();
String.Join(",", stringNums.ToArray())
```

Comment: This shouldn't have happened as [string.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__) works on `IEnumerable`s, which both `List` and `Array` are.