# IEnumerable<string> to comma separated string

Tags: c#, string, ienumerable

I need to convert the `IEnumerable<string> emails` to comma separated `string`.
The `iEnumerable` is actually `Hashset<string>` with emails, I need to generate string with emails separated by `','`

```
em1@hotmail.com, em2@gmail.com, em3@walla.com
```

how can I do it without using loop

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a comma separated list from IList<string> or IEnumerable<string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring)

Comment: No. I am not looking to create a list , but string

Comment: did you even follow the link? The wording in the title might be a bit unfortunate but it is exactly the same question, with answers for C# 2.0, 3.5, and 4.0+

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = String.Join(", ", emails);
```