# Exporting list of strings to an excel cell using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm currently trying to export some DataTable data to excel. One of the columns in my table is `List<string>`. I first create a **DataTableReader** and then try to load the data into a worksheet using **LoadFromDataReader** like so:

```
public static ToReader(List<object> data)
{
    var toReturn = new DataTable();
    // Complex code about creating the data
    return new DataTableReader(toReturn);
}
//...
public static Export(List<object> data)
{
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        // add the content into the Excel file
        ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Data"];
        ws.Cells[startCell].LoadFromDataReader(ToReader(data), true);
        //....
    }
}
```

All the data gets exported to excel just fine except for the column which contains `List<string>`. For this column I would expect the cell value to be comma separated values of that list, instead I just get the first element of the list.

E.g. if the list was ***{"Fee", "Fi", "Fo", "Fum"}***, I would expect the cell value to be ***"Fee, Fi, Fo, Fum"***, instead I get ***"Fee"***.

From debugging I see that data is correctly written to the DataTableReader, so the problem must be with loading it into excel. 
What am I doing wrong here, and how can I have this List column correctly exported to excel?

Comment: You seem to have obscured away some code, but I assume you might use `.Join()` to create a comma separated string from a list [Creating a comma separated list from IList<string> or IEnumerable<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446/creating-a-comma-separated-list-from-iliststring-or-ienumerablestring)

Comment: @Equalsk, thanks for your answer. I omitted the data generating code because it's actually using reflection to get values from the model classes using data attributes, which isn't really relevant. I was thinking of joining strings like you suggested, but was hoping that EPPlus has a built in mechanism to deal with columns which are collections.

Comment: @devlincarnate thanks, as mentioned above my code is generic and using reflection, so would prefer not to special case something if I don't have to. I was hoping that EPPlus has a way of dealing with columns which are collections. It clearly does something (printing just first element of the collection), but just not what I want it to do.

Comment: You can just always use `Join()`...it accepts a string as input as well as a collection.

Comment: This is not a CSV question so much.  It is specific to how Epplus handles table rows that contain non-string object types.  If it detects is an `IEnumerable` it will actually cast it and grab the FIRST entry and call `ToString()` implicitly on the item.  You can see that here:  https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.3/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L3714  We should re open to give a proper answer.  Basicially, your best bet would be to generate the list yourself and store the as a string in the data table rather than a collection.

Comment: @ErnieS, thanks for pointing to the EPPlus code. The way you described it is exactly what I'm getting which in my opinion is a wrong way of handling collections. That's why I thought that I might be missing some config or other way of telling EPPlus how to handle my lists. What you suggest as a solution is what I basically did, but still don't like it and expect EPPlust to be able to handle columns that are lists properly.

Comment: Also @ErnieS, sorry I'm relatively new to this, so not sure if I closed the question (if I did it was not intentional) and if I need to reopen it somehow, or best would be to just open an enhancement ticket for EPPlus if this is their expected behavior?

Comment: @mdmilic Glad to see you got it work.  No, you didnt close it, others did.  They thought it was a dup of another question which it is not.  So it looks like it has been reopened which is good.  I will post an answer just so anyone else who has the same question sees it.  I aggree with you - its a strange choice on the part of Epplus but the code references a bug so I assume there is a specific reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a CSV question so much. It is specific to how Epplus handles table rows that contain non-string object types. If it detects is an `IEnumerable` it will actually cast it and grab the FIRST entry and call `ToString()` implicitly on the item. You can see that here:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/v4.5.3/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet.cs#L3714

Its a strange call but I assume the referenced bug has something to do with it.

Your best bet would be to generate the list yourself and store the as a string in the data table rather than a collection. This would require you to change the underlying data type unfortunately but it would allow you to do something like:

```
string.Join(", ", myList)
```

into your object and push into the `LoadFromDataReader`.