# Linq Lambda Join + GroupBy + String.Join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

So I have two DbSets worth of data, let's call them A and B.  I want to join these together on two fields.  I have that statement no problem.  Once the two data sets are joined I get a distinct set or rows.  Lastly, and this is the part I need help with, I need to find all rows where all fields are the same, except one column, and that column needs to be combined into a comma separate list.

Columns: Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5

Data Row 1: A, Apple, 1, 2, 3

Data Row 2: A, Orange, 1, 2, 3

Data Row 3: A, Cherry, 3, 2, 1

The data above is already joined and has distinct values.  The code I need takes this data and outputs the following:

Columns: Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, Field5

Data Row 1: A, [Apple, Orange], 1, 2, 3

Data Row 2: A, Cherry, 3, 2, 1

When the data in Field1, 3, 4, and 5 are the same I need to join all the items in Field2 into a comma separated string or List, ideally.  I should also note that currently the data rows are an anonymous type.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799446

Comment: Use `GroupBy` then `Select`. Please show your code - are you using LINQ Fluent/Lambda Syntax or Query Syntax?

Comment: @NetMage I am using LINQ Lambda syntax.  I think I found a solution at: https://forums.asp.net/t/2067132.aspx?How+to+Concatenate+multiple+rows+into+a+single+row+in+LINQ.  I did not post the code because the actual wording is proprietary and I did not have time to work up a sample.  If the code I found works I will post the working solution.